# WaitForSingleObject always return WAIT_OBJECT_0

Tags: waitforsingleobject

I don't set the event signaled, but the WaitForSingleObject always returned. I create a event in the main thread.

```
g_hHeartMonitorEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
```

Then in another thread, I use WaitForSingleObject to wait the event signaled.

`

```
while(true)
{
    DWORD dwResult = WaitForSingleObject(lpThis->g_hHeartMonitorEvent, 90 * 1000);
    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == dwResult)
    {
        LogWriteEx("WaitForSingleObject：dwResult = WAIT_OBJECT_0");
        continue;
    }
}
```

`

I find that WaitForSingleObject always returns WAIT_OBJECT_0. The setevent only is called in one place.
The machine has a single-core CPU.

Answer (score 0):

It will occur if the handle of event has been close by some unknown reason.

Comment: Note, however, that that behavior is not guaranteed: `WaitForSingleObject` [explicitly documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) that "if this handle is closed while the wait is still pending, the function's behavior is undefined". Closing a handle that's still in use should always be considered a bug (and handles are generally not closed mysteriously but only by explicit calls to `CloseHandle`; closing a handle without the process being responsible is generally reserved for specialized debugging tools).